# Is there a WP-Plugin to convert PNG to GIF?

Tags: plugins, uploads

I want to upload PNG-files, which convert wordpress in GIF-files. Is there a WP-Plugin to convert PNG to GIF? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no plugin for that as far as I know. The best solution for this would simply be to convert your pngs to gifs somewhere online, you have a lot of converters, and also bulk converters that may help you. [Try this one](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-gif)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Usce. Thats a good option.
(In the plugin »Imsanity« is it possible to convert PNG in JPEG, so i thought it is possible to convert GIF to PNG too.)

Comment: I understand, but Imsanity is converting images just becasue of their size its main purpose is not the convertion of file type. Also if you answer that I provided you helpful please rate it and pick it as best answer so the other users have better orientation. Thanks.

Comment: I need still 15 reputation points and then i rate this. :)